# Finding the unique elements in a column of a data from terminal/Unix

Tags: sorting, unix

So, I have a dataset which is of the format:

```
BBS1    Bbs1    reg 7   Heart
ASAP2   Asap2   reg 5   Heart
SPATA22 Spata22 reg 1   Heart
MYLK4   Mylk4   reg 1   Heart
ATP8A1  Atp8a1  reg 5   Heart
```

Now the organ name (here Heart) can be different. I there are several organs that the data is about. I am wondering how I can figure out the names of  the unique elements of that column(column 5)? The data file is huge.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you just want the unique values in column 5, you can do:

```
awk '{print $5}' inputFile | sort | uniq
```

or:

```
awk '{print $5}' inputFile | sort -u
```

Or, if you don't want to use `sort` for some reason, you can use `awk` on its own:

```
awk '{arr[$5] = 1} END {for (key in arr) {print key}}' inputFile
```

The `arr[$5] = 1` command that executes for every line simply updates an associative array using column 5 as the key. If the entry doesn't exist, it is created. If it does exist, it's simply overwritten.

Then, once you've finished the file, you output all the keys of that associative array. Due to the create-or-overwrite nature, this will be the keys with duplicates removed.

For a huge file, switching from an `O(n log n)` sort to an `O(n)` process may speed things up. But, as with all optimisation efforts, *measure, don't guess!*

---

As an aside, you can sometimes make things more efficient if you have extra knowledge about the input data. This may or may not be the case for you, but I once had a situation where the data was already mostly sorted on (in your case) column 5 (think just adding entries to the end of an otherwise-sorted-on-organ file).

That meant I would get long sequences of `heart` or other organs but occasionally, you might get a mix like:

```
heart
heart
heart
heart
heart
heart
liver
liver
lung
heart    <= What the ?
```

With extra information like this, you can speed things up:

```
awk '{print $5}' | uniq | sort | uniq
```

Now, that *may* look strange to you but the fact that the incoming data has long stretches of identical organs means that the first `uniq` (at O(n)) greatly reduces the workload of the `sort` (at best, O(n log n)).

In the data shown above, `sort` would only have to process four items:

```
heart    <= uniquified one
liver
lung
heart
```

rather than ten.

The final `uniq` is then just to clean up the out-of-order ones in the original list.

As I said, that may not be the case for you but it's sometimes advantageous to think outside the box like that.

Answer (score 1):

`awk '{print $5}' <file> | sort -u`

> awk {`print $5`}

will print the fifth column of the data

> sort -u

sorts the data alphabetically, and then only outputs unique elements.

Comment: Warwick, `uniq` _requires_ the data to be sorted. Otherwise "a,b,a,a,c" will give you "a,b,a,c" (two copies of "a") rather than "a,b,c".

Comment: `awk` can read files on its own; there's no need for `cat` in the first command line.

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler Thanks. Updated.